# How can I get the number of seconds since 1970 without the milliseconds in C#

Tags: c#

I am using this:

```
var a = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds.ToString()
```

But this gives me:

1546582625.5838

How can I get this rounded to the number of seconds without the .5838?

Comment: Just round it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast or Round Truncate

```
var a = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))
                     .TotalSeconds;

var b = Math.Round(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))
                           .TotalSeconds);

var c = Math.Truncate(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))
                           .TotalSeconds);
```